# IIS server connection problems after changing applicationUrl

Tags: .net, iis-express

I've set up a pretty basic API with .NET Entity framwework (basic weather forecast template). At the beginning everything was fine, the IIS server starts fine, but once I change the `applicationUrl` in the Json startup file, I get `Failed to register URL "http://mywebsite:49892/" for site "API" application "/". Error description: Access denied. (0x80070005)`.
In my hosts file I have set up `mywebsite` to my computer's IP, it works in the browser.
After changing the URL back to `http://localhost:49892` I get the same errors.
In the output console of my API I can now see an output like that:

```
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:49892/" for site "API" application "/"
Failed to register URL "https://mywebsite:44533/" for site "API" application "/". Error description: Access denied. (0x80070005)
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44353/" for site "API" application "/"
Registration completed for site "API"
IIS Express is running.
```

Is that normal that I get 3 lines of output instead of just 2? Why is it still registering localhost url instead of mywebsite?
What might be causing the problem of the server failing to connect after ULR change?

Comment: Since you tried to bind to a custom binding (not localhost), IIS Express running under your account (not full IIS) cannot acquire the permissions. You have to run `netsh` command to register that URL manually in advance, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-windows-server or use IisExpressAdminCmd as https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: @LexLi Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. The server is still trying to register localhost and mywebsite, still getting the same access denied errors. Why is it still trying to use localhost instead of the url I've provided?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app with Visual Studio,did you also change the IP address in the Properties?I think that might be the problem since you changed the IP address in the .json file but the application still thinks you are using the old IP.For that you do left-click on your **Application > Properties > Web**  and look for **"Project Url"**.Check if the url is changed.